# Search date in a txt file

Tags: c#, console-application

I am doing an appointment program wherein I am adding few appointments based on date and stored in a text file. I have a problem in displaying the appointment details according to the date entered.The stored appointments in a text file looks like this..

Date & Time :08/08/2013 09:30 AM    Person Name :Shiv

Date & Time :08/08/2013 10:30 AM    Person Name :Sanjay

Date & Time :10/08/2013 09:30 PM    Person Name :Kumar

Problem is when I enter any date to search appointments,suppose there are 2 appointments for that particular date, my output is showing only one appointment.

Example: If I enter date 08/08/2013,There are 2 appointments stored in text file for the entered date but my output is showing only one appointment like this

***Appointment Details***

08/08/2013 09:30 AM Person Name :Shiv

My code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the date to search appointment in (dd/mm/yyyy) format");
string Date = Console.ReadLine();

string str = sr.ReadToEnd();

bool isDate = File.ReadAllText("E:\\Practice/C#/MySchedular.txt").Contains(Date) ? true : false;

if (isDate)        
{             
    string searchWithinThis = str; ;

    int CharacterPos = searchWithinThis.IndexOf(Date);      

    sr.BaseStream.Seek(CharacterPos ,SeekOrigin.Begin);

    str = sr.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("\n*********Appointment Details*********");

    Console.WriteLine("{0}", str);

    Console.WriteLine("\n");    
}            
else        
{           
    Console.WriteLine("No appointment details found for the entered date");        
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are moving to the start of the line in the text file and reading a single line. Therefore, even if there is more than one line with the desired date string, they are not read. You should check the occurance of multiple events for the given date and read accordingly. By the way, regular expressions may be an alternative approach (possibly faster, more reliable and more flexible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this would work:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string filename = @"E:\Practice\C#\MySchedular.txt";
    string fileContent;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the date to search appointment in (dd/mm/yyyy) format");
    string date = Console.ReadLine();

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
    {
        fileContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    if (fileContent.Contains(date))
    {
        string[] apts = fileContent.Split('\n').Where(x => x.Contains(date)).ToArray();

        foreach (string apt in apts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n**Appointment Details**");
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", apt);
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No appointment details found for the entered date");
    }
    Console.Read();
}
```